# How to render full RazorPage to string?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages

I tried to use the solution from https://stackoverflow.com/a/54043063/234954, to render a page as a string (so I can turn it into a PDF), but that only gets me the main view, it doesn't get the layout associated with the page (and so it is missing the style sheets and some header/footers).

How can I render the full page as a string, and not just the partial view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that I could get what I wanted (the whole page) by making two changes to the answer I was looking at:

```
var view = new RazorView(_razorViewEngine,
                _activator,
                new List<IRazorPage>(),
                page,
                HtmlEncoder.Default,
                new DiagnosticListener("ViewRenderService"));
```

changed to :

```
 var view = new RazorView(_razorViewEngine,
                _activator,
                pageModel.PageContext.ViewStartFactories.Select(v => v()).ToList(),
                page,
                HtmlEncoder.Default,
                new DiagnosticListener("ViewRenderService"));
```

and

```
await page.ExecuteAsync();
```

to

```
await view.RenderAsync(viewContext);
```

Note that if the viewstart pages aren't included in the view, then rendering the view produces the same as executing the page.

Answer (score 2):

I used this article code in a recent project to render html to feed into PDF generation.

I used templates in the Views folder so not razor pages.

It works with Layouts and partials in templates.

https://ppolyzos.com/2016/09/09/asp-net-core-render-view-to-string/

Comment: the main difference between this and what I was doing is that the it finds and uses the view instead of the page.  That turned out to be exactly the thing I needed to change.