# Render a Razor Page to string not found layout

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor, asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

**Problem:**
I need to render a Razor Page partial to a string and use [Render a Razor Page to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46540358/render-a-razor-page-to-string)
but Layout **not used** during rendering page.

```
public async Task<string> RenderToStringAsync(string pageName, object model, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var actionContext =
         new ActionContext(
              _httpContext.HttpContext,
              _httpContext.HttpContext.GetRouteData(),
              _actionContext.ActionContext.ActionDescriptor
         );

    using (var sw = new StringWriterWithEncoding(Encoding.UTF8))
    {
        var result = _razorViewEngine.FindPage(actionContext, pageName);

        if (result.Page == null)
        {
            throw new RazaorPageNotFoundException($"The page {pageName} cannot be found.");
        }

        var view = new RazorView(_razorViewEngine,
             _activator,
             new List<IRazorPage>(),
             result.Page,
             HtmlEncoder.Default,
             new DiagnosticListener("ViewRenderService"));


        var viewContext = new ViewContext(
             actionContext,
             view,
             new ViewDataDictionary(new EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new ModelStateDictionary())
             {
                 Model = model
             },
             new TempDataDictionary(
                  _httpContext.HttpContext,
                  _tempDataProvider
             ),
             sw,
             new HtmlHelperOptions()
        );


        var page = ((Page)result.Page);
        
        page.PageContext = new PageContext
        {
            ViewData = viewContext.ViewData,
            HttpContext = _httpContext.HttpContext,
        };

        page.ViewContext = viewContext;

        _activator.Activate(page, viewContext);

        await page.ExecuteAsync();

        return sw.ToString();
    }
}
```

Page code (for test):

```
@page
@{
    Layout = "~skins/_desktop/Views/Layouts/Standart.cshtml";
}
<div>test</div>
```

Layout code (for test):

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="demo-overlay"></div>
    <!-- Wrapper -->
    <div class="page-wrapper-common">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

After rendering page (no layout):

```
<div>test</div>
```

I try:

- constant and relative path to layout,
- explicit set page.IsLayoutBeingRendered and page.Layout

Comment: Hi, you mean @{     Layout = ... } doesn't work? Please detail your question so that we can help.

Comment: I write more details

Comment: I found post with solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62584735/how-to-render-full-razorpage-to-string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to render full RazorPage to string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62584735/how-to-render-full-razorpage-to-string)